# How to disable code formatting for copyright notice

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I manage to prevent the intellij-formatter to destroy my copyright notice, every time it tidies up my source code? The copyright comes from a template and starts with the first line of my source files, so there is *no formatter-on/off* option.

Well, crawling the topics I find a lot of (useful) information on how to disable formatting for specific regions of your source. But when it comes to copyright there's lack of information, though. I do not want to *disable javadoc-formatting*, there should be another solution out there. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Try adding the copyright to the File and Code template (under settings) deselect reformat according to style.

Comment: The copyright comes from a template and starts with the first line of my source files, so there is no formatter-on/off option. can you show an example ? Only if my answer does not work for you.

Comment: @KennethClark that's an interesting point, but it would force me do do this on a per project setting. In my multi module project I have to find another workaround.

Comment: @fuubah I use the 'copyright profiles'-feature of intellij. So there is only copyright text (velocity template) which will be inserted in the current document as a boxed header-comment.
The result will be oldschool - style like 

/**************
*  copyright *
**************/

starting with the first line of my document.

Comment: it is possible to include the  //@formatter:off inside a html comment. like 

<!---  //@formatter:off copyright  //@formatter:on --> ?

Comment: @fuubah it's not possible to do it this way. Meanwhile i found a suitable solution, will post it here.

Comment: Can you re-consider making my answer as the accepted? I think it addresses your issue better than the current accepted answer.

Comment: @vivekmore, sorry, your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: could you give an example of your copyright - before and after the auto format by the ide? I only ask because I've fixed this issue for myself and would like to know what is it that's not working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was not able to preserve the proper layout with block comments, i figured out another suitable solution:

I used **line comment formatting** for the copyright header.

Thank you guys for your quick suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting **Generate "<p>" on empty lines** under

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > JavaDoc > Other

Uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this:

```
    //@formatter:off
    your code / copyright
    //@formatter:on
```

between off and on the code/copyright should be skipped for formatting

//@formatter:off deactivates the formatter

//@formatter:on activates the formatter again

Comment: it's a bit of a clutter in code, but it works fine. It would be cleaner if you could do it with an annotation on method level, imho. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try out the Copyright plugin.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/88?pr=

It should be able to preserve your copyright notice at the top of your source files, and also apply it to new files or to existing files that are missing the notice on-the-fly whenever you reformat or check in a file.

Comment: I'm using this plugin in v 8.1. I guess it's the java-formatter of intellij which does not preserve blank spaces  - causing the whole header to look like a piece of crap.

Comment: When you use this plugin, does it work? Does this solve your issue?

Comment: sry no, it did  the requested job, until the java formatter destroyed the layout. I've posted my only suitable solution few mins ago.